# finding combination of columns which maximizes a quantity

Tags: pandas, join

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
  cuid  day  transactions
0    a  mon             1
1    a  tue             2
2    b  tue             2
3    b  wed             1
```

For each 'cuid' (customer ID) I want to find the day that maximizes the number of transactions. For e.g. for the above df, the output should be a df which looks like

```
 cuid  day  transactions
1    a  tue             2
2    b  tue             2
```

I've tried code which looks like:

```
dd   = {'cuid':['a','a','b','b'],'day':['mon','tue','tue','wed'],'transactions':[1,2,2,1]}
df   = pd.DataFrame(dd)
dfg  = df.groupby(by=['cuid']).agg(transactions=('transactions',max)).reset_index()
```

But I'm not able to figure out how to join `dfg` and `df`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach1**

`idxmax` gives you the index at which a certain column value (which is `transaction` here) is the maximum.

First we set the index,

```
step1 = df.set_index(['day', 'cuid'])
```

Then we find the idxmax,

```
indices = step1.groupby('cuid')['transactions'].idxmax()
```

and we get the result

```
step1.loc[indices].reset_index()
```

**Approach2**

```
df.groupby('cuid')\
    .apply(lambda df: df[df['transactions']==df['transactions'].max()])\
    .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thank you. If the maximum is not unique is there a way to return indices of all maxima?

Comment: pls check out the 2nd apprach